# Using ID3D11DeviceContext::Map to update a dynamic texture results in offset or incomplete data

Tags: directx, directx11, tilemap, texture-atlas

**Background**

I'm generating a memory texture at load time to store the offsets into a texture atlas for a tilemap as described here [Any way to combine instantiated sprite renderers into one texture so I can apply into a plane at runtime?](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/135282/any-way-to-combine-instantiated-sprite-renderers-into-one-texture-so-i-can-apply/135307#135307) (but in DirectX, not Unity.)

I then read that texture at runtime in the geometry shader to generate a tile mesh from each tile. This works for static tiles. Animated tiles require that the tile indicies be updated in the texture every frame.

**Problem**

This is where I'm stuck. The data loaded into the texture is not the same when it is retrieved via a call to `ID3D11DeviceContext::Map`. The stride, pitch, or even the format is different such that the texture does not get fully updated or the wrong pixels are generated.

**Question**

Given the implementation of `UpdateTileIndexTexture` below, what am I doing wrong in order to fully overwrite the initial texture data with the correct pixel data?

**Implementation**

Initial generation of the dynamic texture. This step works.

```cpp
void Map::GenerateTileIndexTexture() noexcept {
    const auto dims = CalcMaxDimensions();
    const auto width = static_cast<std::size_t>(dims.x);
    const auto height = static_cast<std::size_t>(dims.y);
    std::vector<Rgba> data(width * height, Rgba::Black);
    auto data_iter = std::begin(data);
    for(auto& layer : _layers) {
        for(auto& tile : *layer) {
            const auto* def = tile.GetDefinition();
            const auto coords = def->GetSprite()->GetCurrentSpriteCoords();
            data_iter->r = static_cast<unsigned char>(coords.x);
            data_iter->g = static_cast<unsigned char>(coords.y);
            ++data_iter;
        }
    }
    _tile_index_texture = _renderer.Create2DTextureFromMemory(data, static_cast<unsigned int>(width), static_cast<unsigned int>(height), BufferUsage::Dynamic);
    auto* mat = GetTileMaterial();
    mat->SetTextureSlot(Material::TextureID::Normal, _tile_index_texture.get());
}
```

Implementation of `Create2DTextureFromMemory` for reference:

```cpp
std::unique_ptr<Texture> Renderer::Create2DTextureFromMemory(const std::vector<Rgba>& data, unsigned int width /*= 1*/, unsigned int height /*= 1*/, const BufferUsage& bufferUsage /*= BufferUsage::STATIC*/, const BufferBindUsage& bindUsage /*= BufferBindUsage::SHADER_RESOURCE*/, const ImageFormat& imageFormat /*= ImageFormat::R8G8B8A8_UNORM*/) const noexcept {
    D3D11_TEXTURE2D_DESC tex_desc{};
    
    //...Snip

    // Setup Initial Data
    D3D11_SUBRESOURCE_DATA subresource_data = {};

    subresource_data.pSysMem = data.data();
    subresource_data.SysMemPitch = width * sizeof(Rgba);
    subresource_data.SysMemSlicePitch = width * height * sizeof(Rgba);

    Microsoft::WRL::ComPtr<ID3D11Texture2D> dx_tex{};

    //If IMMUTABLE or not multi-sampled, must use initial data.
    bool isMultiSampled = tex_desc.SampleDesc.Count != 1 || tex_desc.SampleDesc.Quality != 0;
    bool isImmutable = bufferUsage == BufferUsage::Static;
    bool mustUseInitialData = isImmutable || !isMultiSampled;

    HRESULT hr = _rhi_device->GetDxDevice()->CreateTexture2D(&tex_desc, (mustUseInitialData ? &subresource_data : nullptr), &dx_tex);
    bool succeeded = SUCCEEDED(hr);
    if(succeeded) {
        return std::make_unique<Texture2D>(*_rhi_device, dx_tex);
    } else {
        return nullptr;
    }
}
```

Attempt at updating the dynamic texture at runtime:

````cpp
void Map::UpdateTileIndexTexture() noexcept {
    const auto dims = CalcMaxDimensions();
    const auto width = static_cast<std::size_t>(dims.x);
    const auto height = static_cast<std::size_t>(dims.y);
    std::vector<Rgba> data(width * height, Rgba::Black);
    auto data_iter = std::begin(data);
    for(auto& layer : _layers) {
        for(auto& tile : *layer) {
            if(const auto* def = tile.GetDefinition(); def != nullptr) {
                const auto spriteCoords = Vector2{def->GetSprite()->GetCurrentSpriteCoords()};
                data_iter->r = static_cast<unsigned char>(spriteCoords.x);
                data_iter->g = static_cast<unsigned char>(spriteCoords.y);
                ++data_iter;
            }
        }
    }

    D3D11_MAPPED_SUBRESOURCE resource{};
    auto* dx_context = _renderer.GetDeviceContext()->GetDxContext();
    auto* dx_resource = _tile_index_texture->GetDxResource();
    if(HRESULT hr = dx_context->Map(dx_resource, 0, D3D11_MAP_WRITE_DISCARD, 0U, &resource); SUCCEEDED(hr)) {
        std::memcpy(resource.pData, data.data(), data.size() * sizeof(Rgba));
        dx_context->Unmap(dx_resource, 0);
    }
}
```
````

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the returned pitch from your map call - you're assuming it's width * 4 (for 32-bit RGBA) but it may not be (particularly if your texture is not a power of 2 or it's width is not a multiple of 4).

You can only memcpy the entire block in one operation if pitch is equal to width * number of bytes in the format. Otherwise you must memcpy one row at a time.

Sample code, excuse C-isms:

```
// assumes that src and dst are 32-bit RGBA data
unsigned *src; // this comes from whatever your input is
unsigned *dst = (unsigned *) msr.pData; // msr is a D3D11_MAPPED_SUBRESOURCE derived from ID3D11DeviceContext::Map

// width and height come from ID3D11Texture2D::GetDesc
for (int i = 0; i < height; i++)
{
    memcpy (dst, src, width * 4); // copy one row at a time because msr.RowPitch may be != (width * 4)
    dst += msr.RowPitch >> 2; // msr.RowPitch is in bytes so for 32-bit data we divide by 4 (or downshift by 2, same thing)
    src += width; // assumes pitch of source data is equal to width * 4
}
```

You can, of course, also include a test for `if (msr.RowPitch == width * 4)` and do a single memcpy of the entire thing if it's true.

Comment: To copy a row at a time, is the terminating condition `for(auto i = 0; i < resource.DepthPitch; i += resource.RowPitch) { std::memcpy(resource.pData + i, data.data() + i, resource.RowPitch); }`?

Comment: No, depthpitch is for 3d textures. Use width and height of the texture. I'm on mobile at the moment so it's not easy to provide code, but I can do so later if required.

Comment: Could you provide an example?

Comment: This works great. I tend to avoid low-level C functions like `memcpy` unless I have to and this was one of those cases. Makes getting it right the first time more difficult.

Comment: See the [DirectXTex](https://github.com/microsoft/DirectXTex) project for numerous examples of 'row-by-row' copies.

Comment: @ChuckWalbourn Do you have one in mind specifically?

Comment: For interop with DX11 APIs, see [DirectXTexD3D11.cpp](https://github.com/microsoft/DirectXTex/blob/master/DirectXTex/DirectXTexD3D11.cpp)